# Data Transfer in AX

Tags: axapta, dynamic-sql, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, erp

I just started a new Project `_NewEnglandPatriots`.

EDTs:

- FirstName (extends Name)
- SecondName(extends Name)
- LastName (extends Name)
- Position  (String)
- PlayerBirthday (Date)
- JerseyNumber (Integer)

Tables:

- SycTeamRoster (I've dragged all my EDTs to the "Fields" of the table)

Forms:

- TeamRoster (I've dragged all the fields into my SimpleList design)

---

I have inserted the following player data to the form without a problem:

Thomas Edward
Patrick
Brady
12
Quarterback
03.08.1977

Next I wrote a Job `insertTeamMembers`, within which I insert the member with the following code:

```
static void insertTeamMembers(Args _args)
{
    SycTeamRoster       newEnglandTable;

    container           teammembers;
    container           conTake;
    int                 i;
    ;

    teammembers = [["Khashayar" ,"Goudarzi", 1, "Quarterback", 28,02,1990]];

    ttsBegin;
    for(i=1; i<=conLen(teammembers); i++)
    {
        conTake= conPeek(teammembers,i);

        newEnglandTable.clear();
        newEnglandTable.SycVorname          = conPeek(teammembers,1);
        newEnglandTable.SycNachname         = conPeek(teammembers,2);
        newEnglandTable.SycJerseyNumber     = conPeek(teammembers,3);
        newEnglandTable.SycPosition         = conPeek(teammembers,4);
        newEnglandTable.SycPlayerBirthday   = conPeek(teammembers,5);
        newEnglandTable.insert();
    }
    ttsCommit;
 }
```

The problem is that I get the following data to the Form and Table:

FirstName: Khashayar
SecondName: empty, but because I left it that way
LastName: empty
JerseyNumber: 0
FieldPosition: 0
Birthday: empty

What is causing these empty fields in the table?

Comment: Sorry as FirstName I off Course get Khashayar

Answer (score 3):

These lines are using `teammembers` instead of `conTake`

> `newEnglandTable.SycVorname          = conPeek(teammembers,1);`

Change to

> `newEnglandTable.SycVorname          = conPeek(conTake,1);`

And the way you have data entered in your nested container, specifically `28,02,1990` is going to be a problem.

This appears to be a learning exercise, so I don't want to solve the entire thing for you.

Comment: Thank You. 
I got it, I have to you instead of teammember conTake. 

Why is it going to be Problem ?

Comment: Elements in a container are separated by commas. That looks like a date to me, but to the compiler, it looks like 3 separate integers. You need to store the date in a different format.